# wrong sequence tableview.reloaddata() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I'm writing a code for a 'checklist' creator'. There are several parts in the application. One is for creating a new checklist from scratch. Based on the choices the user makes a row of a checklist will have a checkbox, input field or yes/no segmentswitch. I managed to set this all up using Parse, but there is one problem.

When I click on a button, a new row is added and I can enter some date here.
Then I can click that same button again and the same happens etc.

However, when I'm adding my fifth row, the fifth row will become the current first row and the first row is now an empty one. I've added the code below. It's quitte long due to all different variable's, but I think the most important ones are the
'add' IBaction and the part where the table view is configured. Can someone help me solving my problem?

Thanks,
Sven

[Picture: This is what the mistake looks like. The last row is actually the one I configured as first row. The first row is now empty (off screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlV4r.png)

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Foundation

var emptyone = true
class Homescreen: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var topField = [""]
var first = Bool()
var label1 = [""]
var switchEnab = [false]
var fieldEnab = [false]
var yesnoEnab = [false]
var topSegmentEnab = [false]
var topFieldEnab = [false]
var segmentName0 = [""]
var segmentName1 = [""]
var segmentName2 = [""]
var messageEnab = [false]
var message1 = [""]
var labelEnab = [false]
var field1 = [""]
var switch1 = [false]
var topSegment = [1]
var yesno1 = [1]
var nummer = Int()



// Add a new row
@IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {

    first = true



    self.label1.append("" as String!)
    self.topField.append("" as String!)
    self.segmentName0.append("" as String!)
    self.segmentName1.append("" as String!)
    self.segmentName2.append("" as String!)
    self.message1.append("" as String!)
    self.field1.append("" as String!)
    self.switchEnab.append(false)
    self.fieldEnab.append(false)
    self.topFieldEnab.append(false)
    self.yesnoEnab.append(false)
    self.topSegmentEnab.append(false)
    self.messageEnab.append(false)
    self.labelEnab.append(false)
    self.switch1.append(false)
    self.yesno1.append(1)
    self.topSegment.append(1)

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}


@IBOutlet var celOpmaak: UITableView!


// Function initators
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
func busy(){
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// Final save of the checklist
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if last == true{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.first = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



            busy()

        let newValues = PFObject(className: "clTypes")


        newValues["taskName"] = ""
        newValues["dateStamp"] = "  -  -  "
        newValues["topSegmentEnab"] = self.topSegmentEnab
        newValues["segmentName0"] = self.segmentName0
        newValues["segmentName1"] = self.segmentName1
        newValues["segmentName2"] = self.segmentName2
        newValues["topFieldEnab"] = self.topFieldEnab
        newValues["topField"] = self.topField
        newValues["label1"] = self.label1
        newValues["label1Enab"] = self.labelEnab
        newValues["fieldEnab"] = self.fieldEnab
        newValues["field1"] = self.field1
        newValues["switchEnab"] = self.switchEnab
        newValues["switch1"] = self.switch1
        newValues["yesnoEnab"] = self.yesnoEnab
        newValues["yesno1"] = self.yesno1
        newValues["topSegment"] = self.topSegment
        newValues["messageEnab"] = self.messageEnab
        newValues["message1"] = self.message1
        newValues["clType"] = clType1
        newValues["checklistTitle"] = checklistTitle1
        newValues.saveInBackground()
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        self.displayAlert("Checklist saved", message: "The checklist has been saved to the server succesfully")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("overview", sender: self)


    }else{
        displayAlert("No final button", message: "Please add a 'last' cell to the checklist")

    }
}



// VIEWDIDLOAD
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.field1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.message1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.topField.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.segmentName0.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.segmentName1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.segmentName2.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.switchEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.yesnoEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.topFieldEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.fieldEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.messageEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.labelEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.switch1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.topSegmentEnab.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.yesno1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.topSegment.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
   last = false
    //var helloWorldTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    toeVoegen.wraps = false
    toeVoegen.autorepeat = false
    toeVoegen.maximumValue = 80
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return label1.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cel", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! creatorCellTableViewCell
    if cell == nil{
        print("hoi")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cel", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! creatorCellTableViewCell

    if first == true{
    cell.option1.delegate = self
    func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

        print(self.label1)
        print(Int(toeVoegen.value))
    label1[indexPath.row] = cell.labelField.text!
}else{

// This part is only called when the 'final save button' has been activated

label1[indexPath.row] = cell.labelField.text!
field1[indexPath.row] = ""
yesno1[indexPath.row] = 1
topField[indexPath.row] = ""
        // switchEnab, fieldEnab, yesnoEnab
    if cell.degreeField.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        labelEnab[indexPath.row]=false
        topFieldEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        topSegmentEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        segmentName0[indexPath.row] = ""
        segmentName1[indexPath.row] = ""
        segmentName2[indexPath.row] = ""

        if cell.typeField.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        switchEnab[indexPath.row] = false
        fieldEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        yesnoEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        messageEnab[indexPath.row]=false
        message1[indexPath.row]=cell.messageField.text!
        }else if cell.typeField.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        switchEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        fieldEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        yesnoEnab[indexPath.row] = false
            if cell.messageSwitch.on == true{
            messageEnab[indexPath.row]=cell.messageSwitch.on
            message1[indexPath.row]=cell.messageField.text!
            }else{
            messageEnab[indexPath.row]=false
            message1[indexPath.row]="hallo"
            }
        }else if cell.typeField.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{

        labelEnab[indexPath.row]=false
        switchEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        fieldEnab[indexPath.row] = false
        yesnoEnab[indexPath.row] = true
        messageEnab[indexPath.row]=false
        message1[indexPath.row]=""
        }


    }else if cell.degreeField.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        switchEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        fieldEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        yesnoEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        labelEnab[indexPath.row]=true
        messageEnab[indexPath.row]=false
        message1[indexPath.row]=""
            if cell.topVeld.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        topSegmentEnab[indexPath.row] = false
        topFieldEnab[indexPath.row] = true


        segmentName0[indexPath.row] = cell.option1.text!
        segmentName1[indexPath.row] = cell.option2.text!
        segmentName2[indexPath.row] = cell.option3.text!
            } else{

                topSegmentEnab[indexPath.row]=true
                topFieldEnab[indexPath.row]=false
            }
    }

    }
}
    return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is related to the fact that you are reusing cells. Every time you do this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cel",
   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! creatorCellTableViewCell
```

there is a chance (a very likely chance as soon as you have more rows than fit on your screen) that a different cell is returned than was originally at that index. For example, as soon as you scroll up to row #5 and row #1 is no longer on the screen you could be getting the same exact cell that was at row #1 being displayed at row #5. When you are reusing cells you have to set the state on the cell every single time. For example:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cel",
   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! creatorCellTableViewCell

cell.labelField.text! = label1[indexPath.row]
// do this for every field that needs to be set
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it has something to do with that. I changed my code a bit and once the new code you mentioned is simulated it changes the text values to what is in the array(s). The problem is that my array is empty when I first load it. So first I need to save the value of the textfield in my array, then I add a new row and then the values of each row should match with the index of the array. Unfortunately this is still not the case. The printed array also shifts after the 4th row. Is there a way to use the indexpath.row method outside the dequereusable.... func?

Comment: I also discovered that the problem is mostly caused by scrolling. Also when you hide the keyboard (= scrolling?) the problem occurs. It even looks like (using some prints) that the code automatically calls 'reloaddata' when you are scrolling. Maybe enabling this might be the solution? Is that possible?